# Percorrer elementos DOM com a função each

Tags: jquery

Gostaria de um exemlo de como poderia fazer isso usando o Jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá , veja um exemplo de como você poderia fazer,

```js
$('#my-list li').each(function(index, element) {
  console.log(index + ' : ' + element.innerHTML);
});
```

```html
<ol id="my-list">
  <li>Red</li>
  <li>Green</li>
  <li>Yellow</li>
  <li>Blue</li>
</ol>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Veja se isso ajuda!